# Is it necessary to sanitize wp_set_password user input?

Tags: php, database, login, user-registration, sanitization

I'm trying to add a password form to the WP registration form. See the code below. I was wondering if I need to sanitize this specific user input? (and if so how?)

If I understand it correctly, WP has sanitizion built in for some things, and passwords may be one of them. Is that correct? Will WP sanitize it automatically before adding it to the database?

```php
add_action( 'register_new_user', 'registration_change_pass', 10, 99 );

function registration_change_pass( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_password'] ) ) {
        wp_set_password( $_POST['user_password'], $user_id ); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need to sanitize passwords. You don't want to strip out or rewrite a value on users' set passwords. They will be hashed afterwards, so no need

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected.